# Using HttpURLConnection with BigIp load balancer and Java 1.7

Tags: java, applet, load-balancing, httpurlconnection

Folks,

We have a Java Applet communicating with the server through a BigIp Load-Balancer. The Java Applet is using an HttpURLConnection and the communication protocol is https.

The Load-Balancer implements a cookie based persistence policy to maintain session affinity.
This all works fine when the Java Applet using Java 1.5, 1.6 and early versions of Java 1.7.

Somewhere around Java 1.7.0_21 something went wrong with the Java Applet and now when we open HttpURLConnection for the 2nd time and on, the load balancer does not pass the request to the server but instead replies with the same response sent for the 1st request from the Applet as if thinking the request is for static content that can be cached.

Any ideas what has changed in recent versions of Java with respect to HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: Does `conn.setUseCaches(false)` help? Or can you add some kind of cache-buster, e.g. `url += '?cb=' + System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: setUseCaches(false) solved the problem. If I could up vote your answer a Million times I would have done so.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that you are properly negotiating an SSL connection. You can do this two ways: create an iRule to log to /var/log/ltm:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   log local0. “Requested hostname: [HTTP::host] from IP: [IP::local_addr]”
}
```

Turn on [SSL debug logging](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/15000/200/sol15292.html):

```
tmsh modify /sys db log.ssl.level value Debug
```

If you are failing to negotiate SSL, you will not see anything logged from the iRule, but should have an answer as to why you are failing to handshake. Most often you need to adjust your [cipher string.](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/13000/100/sol13171.html)